# Find another expression for the formula

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

Let there be a collection of sets $\{A_{1},...,A_{m}\}$, where $A_{i}\subseteq\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ for every $i$.

Also let $\beta(J)=\begin{cases} 1 &\text{when }  |\bigcup_{i\in J}A_{i}|\ge s\\0 &\text{otherwise } \end{cases}$

Where $s$ is some natural number.

> Find a better formula for the following expression $$\sum_{i=1}^{m}(-1)^{i-1}\sum_{I\subseteq [m], |I|=i}\beta(I)$$

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is $[m]$ short for $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, m\}$? So $I\subseteq [m]$ means $I\subseteq\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, m\}$?

Comment: @MPW: Yes, it is.